VPN not working on laptop connected through Android phone USB tethering
I used to connect my laptop to the internet via USB tethering from my android phone (running android 6), and then connect to my organization's VPN.
I got myself a new phone, and realized that it blocks VPN connections. Apparently this issue has been discussed before but that was ~7 years ago, and the solutions offered do not work for me. In particular, the "APN protocol" is already set to IPV4.
What is the most recommendable way of getting VPN to work in a laptop connected to the internet with a modern android (in my case it's android 13) through USB tethering or wifi hotspot?

What VPN are we talking about? Often a "blocked VPN" is simply a misconfigured packet size of the UDP VPN layer (packets too large are dropped/discarded). Other VPNs base on HTTPS and thus are really difficult to block.

I connect through GlobalProtect. The exact same configuration works flawlessly if I use my old phone. Internet connection through USB tethering (without VPN) works fine with the new phone, but stops working if I connect to the VPN through GlobalProtect.
